# assigning date to a datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker

I have a list of checkbox with date fields as you can see on the screenshot below. I wanted to assign each currentLeaseExpiration to each date picker value

First is how do we assign each currentLeaseExpiration  from the object as default value of the date picker ?

And when the user check the box or select a checkbox could be one or multiple then it will get all the selected values and pass all the selected as an array of objects.

Maybe someone has an idea with these implementation in Angular typescript.

screenshot

[image]

html code

```
<div *ngFor="let subtenant of currentSubtenants" class="subtenant-form-btn-group">
            <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
              <div class="pharmacy-checkbox">
                <mat-checkbox
                 color="primary"
                 style="margin-left:10px;">
                 <div class="deal-text-label">
                   {{subtenant.subtenantName}}
                </div>
                </mat-checkbox>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="buyout-form-date-picker">
                <mat-label>Current Lease Expiration</mat-label>
                  <input 
                    name = "estimatedClosingDate" 
                    matInput   
                    [min]="currentDate"                
                    [matDatepicker]="currentLeaseExpiration" 
                    [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.currentLeaseExpiration"
                    [required]="isExistingDeal">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="currentLeaseExpiration"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #currentLeaseExpiration></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

sample currentSubtenants object

```
[
    {
        "subtenantName": "Urgent Care MSO, LLC",
        "currentLeaseExpiration": "04/30/2023"
    },
    {
        "subtenantName": "Laboratory Corporation of America",
        "currentLeaseExpiration": "10/10/2028"
    }
]
```

code for getting the list

```
 getListOfCurrentSubtenants() {
      this.partnerRoleIsInProgress = true;
       this._dealService.getCurrentSubtenants(this.transactionData.propertyId)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => this.partnerRoleIsInProgress = false),
        ).subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
            if (res.isSuccess) {
              res.data.forEach(element => {
                if(element.currentLeaseExpiration) {
                  element.currentLeaseExpiration =  AppUtils.convertDateStringToYYYYMMDD(element.currentLeaseExpiration)
                }
              });
              this.currentSubtenants = res.data;
              console.log("res" , this.currentSubtenants)
            }
          },
          error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
          complete: noop
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `dealDispositionFormFields` in your code?

Comment: What were your efforts so far?