# Angular Material Date Picker cannot be dynamically named (angular 9 - latest)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to populate each subtenant name and each current lease expiration to the template but Angular Material Date Picker cannot be dynamically named and it causes an issue , it always show the same date on the date picker although the dates on the object are different.

[image]

Any idea how to solve this one?

template code

```
 <div *ngFor="let subtenant of currentSubtenants; let i = index;" class="subtenant-form-btn-group">
            <div class="deal-form-btn-group-radio" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" >
              <div class="pharmacy-checkbox">
                <mat-checkbox
                 color="primary"
                 style="margin-left:10px;">
                 <div class="deal-text-label">
                   {{subtenant.subtenantName}}
                </div>
                </mat-checkbox>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div >
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="buyout-form-date-picker">
                <mat-label>Current Lease Expiration</mat-label>
                  <input 
                    name="picker"
                    matInput   
                    [min]="currentDate"                
                    [matDatepicker]="picker" 
                    [(ngModel)]=subtenant.currentLeaseExpiration 
                    [required]="isExistingDeal">
                  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

code for getting the object

```
 getListOfCurrentSubtenants() {
      this.partnerRoleIsInProgress = true;
       this._dealService.getCurrentSubtenants(this.transactionData.propertyId)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => this.partnerRoleIsInProgress = false),
        ).subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
            if (res.isSuccess) {
              res.data.forEach(element => {
                if(element.currentLeaseExpiration) {
                  element.currentLeaseExpiration = new Date(element.currentLeaseExpiration)
                }
              });
              this.currentSubtenants = res.data;
              console.log("res" , this.currentSubtenants)
            }
          },
          error: err => this._notificationService.showError(err),
          complete: noop
        });
    }
```

sample object

```
[
    {
        "subtenantName": "Urgent Care MSO, LLC",
        "currentLeaseExpiration": "2023-04-29T16:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "subtenantName": "Laboratory Corporation of America",
        "currentLeaseExpiration": "2028-10-09T16:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try `[value]="subtenant.currentLeaseExpiration"` in input

Comment: you have idea with this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721890/assigning-date-to-a-datepicker passing the selected values into array of objecrts

Comment: @klivladimir now how do I pass its value without using ngModel?

Comment: Maybe FormArray it good option for this
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#date-range-picker-forms
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: can you provide an example answer Sir ?

Comment: [value]= works but the problem is how to I pass it upon submitting ..

Comment: Have no time 
Try this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-angular